# Why do questions on Stack Overflow have to be based on facts?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, subjective

I don't understand: Is the main motto of Stack Overflow to build reputation or to get your problems related to programming get answered?

So what if someone has a problem that may not be answered in terms of facts? As long as it is related to programming, it should be fine. I think that's what SO should be about!

Comment: This is just becoming fascinating.

Comment: you may be interested in Not Constructive (a web site for things that can't be discussed on StackOverflow) http://signup.notconstructive.com/?lrRef=EYHpR

Answer (score 20):

It doesn't make sense to go to the [Smithsonian National Museum of Natural History](http://www.mnh.si.edu/) and complain that they didn't have any paintings by Monet or Rembrandt, or to go to the [National Portrait Gallery](http://www.npg.si.edu/) and complain that they don't have any water slides.

It doesn't make sense to come to Stack Overflow and complain that subjective questions aren't allowed. It's not that we think they are bad - this just isn't the place to ask them.

Comment: I'm glad I learned this before my trip to the National Portrait Gallery. Now I know to leave my swim trunks at home... or just take them to the National Zoo, instead! (You can swim with the polar bears there, right? And pet the lions?)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Glad I caught you in time! I bet that would have been embarrassing. Don't know about the polar bears and lions, but you just missed your opportunity to [drink beer](http://nationalzoo.si.edu/activitiesandevents/celebrations/brew/default.cfm) and play with some of the animals.

Answer (score 1):

A question that is fine, "as long as it is related to programming" (see [Programmers, Help Center > Asking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), is more likely meant to be asked on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) than on Stackoverflow.

Subjective questions are allowed there (see the Helper Center Link).

Questions that are appropriate for stackoverflow should cover

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

(from [Stackoverflow, Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Programmers has its own guide about appropiate questions.

Comment: Rather obvious but I'll add a link.

Comment: I meant that I would not say that "as long as it is related to programming" it should go to Programmers, which is how I read your answer on the first passing.

Comment: My point is that his statement would match the Programmers site (if any) and not Stackoverflow. It's not the exact description of what actually should be asked on Programmers.